# App Dynamics for Angular 2 App in IIS - Node.js Agent Installation and Configuration

Tags: node.js, angular, iis, appdynamics

I am trying to assist in setting up AppDynamics with an Angular 2 app that is hosted in IIS. The app is already up and running. There is a part I am having trouble on, the instructions for that part say say:

1) From the root directory of your Node.js application, run this command:
    npm install appdynamics@4.3.5
   For every Node.js application you are instrumenting, insert the following call in the application source code at the first line of the main module (such as the server.js file), before any other require statements:

```
require("appdynamics").profile({
  controllerHostName: '<controller host name>',
  controllerPort: <controller port number>, 
  controllerSslEnabled: false,  // Set to true if controllerPort is SSL
  accountName: '<AppDynamics_account_name>',
  accountAccessKey: '<AppDynamics_account_key>',
  applicationName: 'your_app_name',
  tierName: 'choose_a_tier_name', 
  nodeName: 'choose_a_node_name' 
 });
```

2) Restart you application

I did step 1 locally in the console, but I don't know what to do for step 2. If I add that script to the page I get "The Reference error: require is not defined".
I learned that that function is not meant to run on the browser. It's meant to be run server-side, but I do not see node js or any server.js files on our dev web server.
Does anyone have any suggestions on where to put that snippet.  Will it even work with the current setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the code I was given was completely wrong for angular 2 implementation.  The code they gave me is for running on the web server's side with node js.  Since angular 2 is an SPA that runs on the browser, it would never work.
I did some research and found this example application that I added a few tweaks to: https://github.com/derrekyoung/appd-sampleapp-angular2